# Как отправить значение в com port из другого com порта

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino, com-порт

Мне необходимо считывать данные с одного порта и передать эти значения на другой уже порт

```
    import serial
    import time
    com3 = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=0)
    com3.readline()
    com5 = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=0)
    while 1:
        print com5.readline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В объекте `Serial`, есть методы для чтения(read, readline, readlines) и методы для записи(write, writelines) данных. Из одного порта читаете, в другой записываете.

```
import serial
import time

com1 = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=0)
com2 = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=0)

while True:
    data = com1.readlines()
    if data:
        com2.writelines(data)
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: А зачем 200мс таймаут?

Comment: Таймаут можете уменьшить, но совсем лучше не убирать, так как у вас будет постоянно загружен процессор.

Comment: спасибо, я был близок на самом деле, просто в синтаксисе не прав был) я писал у себя просто write(data), но не сделал условие, как у тебя. Только я еще не проверял, но надеюсь все работает, выглядит убедительно

Comment: Я думаю, что если использовать блокирующее чтение, таймаут не нужен совсем.

Comment: Да, конечно. Если больше ничего не делать, то можно убрать неблокирующее чтение.

Comment: Не понял в чём тут проблема? Обработку сигналов и кода возврата никто не отменял.

Comment: Так а тут и нет никаких проблем. Причем тут обработка сигналов и код возврата? Имеется ввиду, что если нет необходимости в том, чтобы делать какую-то работу, например логгировать, тогда можно использовать неблокирующее чтение.

Comment: Сейчас проблема, я поставил как тут написано. Прописал print data. Мне просто выдает [], без значений. @Avernial

Comment: Write timeout @avernial

Comment: поставил writeTimeout = 0. Но она выполняет процесс, но ничего не работает, ставлю на просто timeout = 0, работает пару секунд и выдает ошибку про Write timeout @Avernial

Comment: А откуда данные читаете? Совпадает ли baudrate? То что вам выдается [], означает лишь то, что увас не приходят данные в порт, либо эти данные идут без сивола новой строки. Если данные идут без символа новой строки, тогда вместо readlines и writelines надо использовать методы read и write.

 write_timeout вообще не нужно трогать.